# How do I build a HashSet from a list?

Tags: elixir

I can build an empty `HashSet`, and I can build larger ones from it like this:

```
HashSet.new |> Set.put(1) |> Set.put(2) |> Set.put(1)
```

But how can I initialize the `HashSet` with a list?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Enum.into`:

```
[1, 2, 1] |> Enum.into(HashSet.new) #=> #HashSet<[1, 2]>
```